# Get count of multiple nodes with no relations in cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to get the count of more than one nodes.

```
MATCH (n1:node1) 
MATCH (n2:node2) 
MATCH (n3:node3) where n3.status = "active" 
return count(n1) as countOfNode1,
count(n2) as countOfNode2,
count(n3) as countOfNode3
```

This query is returning duplicated result as

```
countOfNode1 = 0
countOfNode2 = 0
countOfNode3 = 0
```

where the real count is

```
countOfNode1 = 0
countOfNode2 = 3
countOfNode3 = 1
```

How to do this?

Using 'distinct' also does not solve the problem.
Given as:

```
return count(distinct n1) as countOfNode1,
count(distinct n2) as countOfNode2,
count(distinct n3) as countOfNode3
```

Comment: What do you mean `nodes does not have any relationship`? Where in your query relationships between nodes?

Comment: Nodes n1 and n2 are not related

Comment: Did my answer work?

Comment: No it did not work. It is always returning 0 if any of the value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility I'm thinking of is this

```
MATCH (n1:node1) WITH count(n1) as countOfNode1
MATCH (n2:node2) WITH count(n2) as countOfNode2 
MATCH (n3:node3) where n3.status = "active"  WITH count(n3) as countOfNode3
return countOfNode1,
countOfNode2,
countOfNode3
```

Or maybe

```
MATCH (n1:node1), (n2:node2),(n3:node3 {status:"active"} )
return count(n1) as countOfNode1,
count(n2) as countOfNode2,
count(n3) as countOfNode3
```